# How to decrypt apk encrypted files from a dead phone with known password?

Tags: encryption

My problem is the following:**my phone's screen is dead, the phone has full disk encryption turned on, I know the password, I need to retrieve data on it and I have an encrypted back up**. 
The phone is a Samsung Galaxy S7. I cannot access files by plugging the phone into my computer as I can't unlock the phone without the help of the screen. USB debugging is not enabled.

I have a recent backup of the files made with Samsung's Smart Switch. However, all apk files as well as most files are saved as "enc." files and not readable decrypted files. 
I have tried using gpg and openssl tools to decrypt those files individually with the FDE password of the phone without any success.

What are my options to A) either access my phone's content without the use of the screen B) or decrypt those encrypted backed up files I have given that I know the phone's password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Upon first boot, the device creates a randomly generated 128-bit master key and then hashes it with a default password and stored salt. The default password is: "default_password" However, the resultant hash is also signed through a TEE (such as TrustZone), which uses a hash of the signature to encrypt the master key.
>
> When the user sets the PIN/pass or password on the device, only the 128-bit key is re- encrypted and stored. (ie. user PIN/pass/pattern changes do NOT cause re-encryption of userdata.)

I.e you cannot decrypt the data without knowing the `master key` which is randomly generated and stored on the phone.

You'll need to replace your broken screen.

See [this](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) for more information.

Comment: Where is that quote from? It looks suspicious.

Comment: The quote is from the link in the answer. What seems suspicious about it?

Comment: That's exactly what I feared. Thanks for your help. 
I had hoped I would be able to decrypt this encrypted back up as I would for any encrypted file/container with programs like veracrypt or cryptomator given that I know the password...

Comment: Since the password isn't used to decrypt the data you have no use of the password alone if you don't have access to the encrypted master key, which you don't.

Comment: I assume there is no way to export and back up the encrypted master key from Android devices in case it's broken?

Comment: Unfortunately no. `...extracting the decryption key via chip-off or any other low-level method is not possible, so if you do a chip-off you won’t get the decryption key and won’t be able to decrypt the data.`. See [this](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2017/05/android-encryption-demystified/).